# How should I get the data from JSON into another angular js controller?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and stuck on below code.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: "partials/home.html",
        controller: "mainController",
    })
    .when('/products', {
        templateUrl: "partials/productlist.html",
        //controller: "ProductController",
    })
    .when('/product/:prodID', {
        templateUrl: "partials/product.html",
        controller: "viewController",
    })
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: "partials/contact.html",
        controller: "contactController",
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    });
});

app.controller('ProductController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('partials/productTable.json').success(function(response){
        $scope.datap = response.lists;
    });
 }).
controller('viewController',function($scope,$routeParams){
    $scope.eachproduct = $scope.datap[$routeParams.prodID];
});
```

And my product.html page code will look like this.

```
<div ng-controller="viewController">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li class="active">{{eachproduct.link}}</li>
    </ol>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <figure><img ng-src="{{ }}"></figure>
        <p>
            <a href="">Read More</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is when I navigate to any product page value of {{eachproduct.link}} is not showing.

Any solution will be appriciated.

Comment: you commented out the ProductController within `.when('/products'` ?

Comment: If I remove comment then the ProductController is not working :(

Comment: what are the errors you are getting

Comment: @HieuLe I removed the commented part now productlist.html page is working fine but problem is still there with product.html page. Should I add $rootScope?

Comment: this is because when you go to a product page, it does NOT run the productcontroller code. It will only run the viewController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`

**$rootScope**

The $rootScope is the top-most scope. An app can have only one $rootScope which will be shared among all the components of an app. Hence it acts like a global variable. All other $scopes are children of the $rootScope.

**Sample :**

```
    controller('viewController',['$scope','$routeParams', '$http','$rootScope',function($scope,$routeParams, $http,$rootScope){
    $http.get('partials/productTable.json').success(function(response){
        $scope.datap = response.lists;
       $rootScope.eachproduct = $scope.datap[$routeParams.prodID];
     });
   }]);
```

Comment: But where should I pass the $rootScope in above example? Is it something like below?

Comment: app.controller('ProductController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope){
    $http.get('partials/productTable.json').success(function(response){
        $scope.datap = response.lists;
    });
 }).
controller('viewController',function($scope,$routeParams){
    $rootScope.eachproduct = $scope.datap[$routeParams.prodID];
});

Comment: @VANKD Yes like that only.

Comment: Creating service would be better

Comment: @PankajParkar is it possible for you to provide any example with my code?

Comment: @SANN3 The above $rootScope did not work. In console I'm getting ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined this error

Comment: I've included an example below using a factory which is a type of angular provider, the service that @PankajParkar refers to is another type of provider.

Comment: controller('viewController',['$scope','$routeParams', '$http','$rootScope',function($scope,$routeParams, $http,$rootScope){
$http.get('partials/productTable.json').success(function(response){
    $scope.datap = response.lists;
   $rootScope.eachproduct = $scope.datap[$routeParams.prodID];
});
}]);

This solution helped but only question here is should I again need to call $http call in 'viewController' as well? Should not we limit to one only?

Comment: @VANKD Limit to one time

Comment: @SANN3 I guess now when I'm clicking on "Read More" link only that text is appearing in product.html page. It should fetch data from json file right?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('ProductController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('partials/productTable.json').success(function(response){
        $scope.datap = response.lists;
    });
 }).
controller('viewController',function($scope,$routeParams, $http){
    $http.get('partials/productTable.json').success(function(response){
        $scope.datap = response.lists;
        $scope.eachproduct = $scope.datap[$routeParams.prodID];
    });
});
```

Comment: "ReferenceError: $http is not defined" and product.html still showing me {{eachproduct.link}}

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are looking for is an angular provider such as a factory to store the values in, this will allow the values to be pass values around the controllers while using the routes.

Have a look at this example, while it isn't using routes, the principal is the same:
https://jsbin.com/wiwejapiku/edit?html,js,output

For more information on providers have a look here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Your example would work something like this:

```
app
.factory('productFactory',function(){
    return {
        data: {}
    };
})
.controller('ProductController', function($scope, $http, productFactory){
    $scope.productFactory = productFactory;
    $http.get('partials/productTable.json').success(function(response){
         $scope.productFactory.data = response.lists;
    });
}).
controller('viewController',function($scope,$routeParams, productFactory){
    $scope.productFactory = productFactory;
    $scope.eachproduct = $scope.productFactory.data[$routeParams.prodID];
});
```

Note you would also have to change your view to reference 'productFactory.data' respectively.

Comment: kind of new to this myself. Will every call to productFactory keep calling the code to get the data? or will it only do it once? For example, if there is an ajax call to get the data, then will that get called every time it is injected to the controller?

Comment: No, the call will only happen once, the purpose of providers in angular is to allow you to have a persistant state throughout the application. So any changes you make to the factory would mean that they will be accessible  from anywhere else that they are consumed. The data will only get changed if you change it (either manually or requesting another ajax call).

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.

Comment: @benfes I will also try with factory provider for my learning thanks for the help.

Comment: @benfes how should I change my view? I used your solution but noting is showing on screen. And also no errors in Console.

Comment: You shouldn't need to refactor your view, are you able to post up your code with the changes? Or provide an example on codepen or jsbin?